# How to add a check mark on context menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application with Caliburn Micro. On my DataGrid, I have a context menu with two items, which represent two options two select from. How can I add a check mark on the items?

Here is my code:

```
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu >
                        <MenuItem Header="Treat Invalid Billing Address As Error"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action TreatInvalidBillingAddressAs('Error')]" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Treat Invalid Billing Address As Warning"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action TreatInvalidBillingAddressAs('Warning')]" />
                    </ContextMenu>
   </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

...

```
   public void TreatInvalidBillingAddressAs(string errorOrWarning)
   {
       SelectedFirstEntry.BillingAddressValidation = errorOrWarning;
       Revalidate();
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Set the `IsCheckable` property to true.

Comment: @DavidShochet bind/set [`MenuItem.IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) accordingly

Comment: @dkozl Thanks! But how can I bind IsChecked to a property value on the selected DataGrid row? There is a BillingAddressValidation field in the DataGrid with a corresponding model property.
<MenuItem Header="Treat Invalid Billing Address As Error"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action TreatInvalidBillingAddressAs('Error')]" IsChecked="{Binding BillingAddressValidation, Converter={StaticResource ErrorToBoolConverter}}" />

Comment: @clcto I don't want it to be manually checkable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DavidShochet since this is `ContextMenu` for the whole `DataGrid` and not `DataGridRow` you could use `SelectedItem` for example or you could change `DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle` and define `ContextMenu`, as a `Setter`, for each `DataGridRow` where binding context is your item

Comment: @dkozl I do have a property SelectedFirstEntry... But could you please refer me to an example how this binding is done? Thanks.

Comment: Where is this `BillingAddressValidation` property defined? Is it in view model against whole grid or each row? Seems to as if against each row and if that's the case you need some row data to get this property. If you keep `ContextMenu` against `DataGrid` you can use `SelectedItem` or you can move `ContextMenu` to `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: @dkozl Yes, it is per row. Thus SelectedFirstEntry has a property called BillingAddressValidation. Is it possible to get a working example how binding should be done, as I am not good at this stuff so far? Thanks.

Comment: did you try `IsChecked="{Binding SelectedFirstEntry.BillingAddressValidation, Converter={StaticResource ErrorToBoolConverter}}"`?

Comment: @dkozl Yes, it worked! thanks a lot! Maybe you would want to make your comments an Answer, so that I could mark it as such?

Comment: @DavidShochet sure. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312064/how-to-add-a-check-mark-on-context-menu-item/25315984#25315984) added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to control checked status of the `MenuItem` you could bind [`MenuItem.IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) property to the `BillingAddressValidation` property of your view model.

Since this is a property of view model against each row and `ContextMenu` is defiend against whole `DataGrid` you can use `SelectedFirstEntry` item.

```
<MenuItem ... IsChecked="{Binding SelectedFirstEntry.BillingAddressValidation, Converter={StaticResource ErrorToBoolConverter}}"/>
```